# ButtonBarButton custom rollover/out event

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

What is the best way to add a custom rollover and rollout to a buttonbarbutton? I tried adding the eventlisteners in the custom skin I am using but the mouseevents do not get fired.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I won't say this is the best way to do it by any means, but I do have a solution.

In the ButtonBar Skin I made I add a listener for the creationComplete of the DataGroup and then add a listener to each of the elements inside it.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.mattel.styleguide.events.DesignDropDownEvent;

        import mx.controls.Alert;

        private function init():void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < dataGroup.numElements; i++)
            {
                dataGroup.getElementAt(i).addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver);
                dataGroup.getElementAt(i).addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOut);
            }
        }

        private function onRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //dispatch custom event
        }

        private function onRollOut(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //dispatch custom event
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" width="100%" height="100%" creationComplete="init()">
    <s:layout>
        <s:ButtonBarHorizontalLayout gap="-1"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

This allows the rollover/rollout events to get hit for each button, I can then check the e.currentTarget and see which button was interacted with and dispatch a custom event inside the functions which bubble up to my view.

I was hoping the was a cleaner way to do it and that could very well be the truth and I just don't know how to do it. Any one else have a different idea?

Thanks!